# Conditional method parameters based on Generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am in the process of writing a new TypeScript class which takes a generic value that will be used as the input to a function. If a value isn't given, than the function should not take any inputs.

Ideally the class would be overloaded like this.

```
class Emitter<T = void> {
    public activate(): void // When T is void
    public activate(arg: T): void // When T isn't void
    public activate(arg?: T) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Having the method be a function property works in theory but requires a `@ts-ignore` on the method's implementation.

```js
type OneArgFn<T> = T extends void
    ? () => void
    : (arg: T) => void

interface Emitter<T> {
    readonly activate: OneArgFn<T>
}
```

Another possibility is to export a different constructor when a Generic is provided or not, such as the following

```js
interface EmitterNoArg extends Emitter {
    activate: () => true
}
interface EmitterOneArg<T> extends Emitter<T> {
    activate: (arg: T) => void
}

interface EmitterConstructor {
    new(): Emitter

    new(): EmitterNoArg
    new<T>(): EmitterOneArg<T>
}
```

but then to export it the `unknown` keyword is required.

```js
export default Emitter as unknown as EmitterConstructor
```

These, do not seem to be optimal. Is there a proper way to have conditional arguments based on the Generic's type? I would think TypeScript's new [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) would solve this issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to do it would be using tuples in rest parameters in a separate public signature:

```
type OneArgFn<T> = T extends void
    ? () => void
    : (arg: T) => void

class Emitter<T = void> {
    public activate(...a: Parameters<OneArgFn<T>>): void
    public activate(arg?: T) { /* ... */ }
}

new Emitter().activate();
new Emitter<string>().activate("") // in 3.4 argument names are preserved
```

Comment: Wow, I knew you could infer return types, but it didn't even cross my mind that it could work for arguments as well. I wish the doc's mentioned that. Thanks!

Comment: @MoPro The docs can' t cover it all, but there is a SO community here to help :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the benefit of having the second overload of `activate` in this solution? Is there a situation where having just the first alone is insufficient? The code in the first could just as easily check `if a[0] === undefined` as the code in the second checks if `arg` is undefined.  Thanks!